# How to create a class that holds array of objects of another class , how to manipulate the other class private attributes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

```
// this is the first point class header 
class Point : public CWaypoint{
public:             //temporarily
    string m_description;
public:
    Point();
    virtual ~Point();
    void print();
    Point(string name, string description, double latitude,  double longitude);
    void getAllDataByReference( string& name,string& description, double& latitude,double& longitude);
};



// This is the database class header

class Database 
{
private:                    
    Point m_POI[10];      // Point is the other class
    int m_noPoi;
public:
    Database();
    virtual ~Database();
    void addPoI(string name,string description,double latitude,double longitude);
    Point * getPointerToPoi(string name);
}
```

Comment: Please, in the future, accompany your code with some text.

Comment: What are specific problems you have encountered?

Comment: "how to manipulate the other class private attributes" you probably need public methods that manipulate the private attributes.

Comment: you cannot maniplulate another class private data. Thats the whole point of `private`. If you want to manipulate member from outside the class then dont make them private. (well, there is `friend`, but that is for special cases only)

Comment: I want to get the array elements and store them in the database class and to print them

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector`?

Comment: its a school assignment

Comment: I am trying to add the function that get the private values ( get by reference ) in the Database class but I cant write it correct  pointertoPoiI[i].getAllDataByReference(&name,&description,&latitude,&longitude);

Comment: @Mrek Remove the ampersands, `&`, from the function call.

Answer (score 0):

First, to add to the array, you can just rely on the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator, which does a shallow copy of all fields:

```
void Database::addPoI(string name,string description,double latitude,double longitude) {
    if (m_noPoi >= 10) // handle error
    m_POI[m_noPoi++] = Point(name, description, latitude, longitude);
}
```

Since the data is private, you can't directly access it (ignoring "friend"ship). However, you can read the data (via a copy of it) through `point::getAllDataByReference()`.